# Multiple apps from one project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, build-process

I have a little problem.. which I know there is a fix for, I just don't know what it is.

The problem is the following. A few weeks ago (2 or so) I had to remove 4 apps from the appstore due to a data problem on my server side. I decided to upgrade all the apps to the latest version at the same time giving them some new features. (I have 6 of the same apps out there, targeting different airports). The difference between these versions are the following:

- A set of 50-80 or so images that combine the map of each airport. The filenames are the same in each app. (How do I solve that?)
- The name of the app
- The Default.png (and those for iPad and retina of course)
- The App Icon
- The content of a details page (which exists in a .plist file)
- The content of the "About" page where the page refers back to the app
- Some localize content, refering back to the airport the app targets.
- The provisioning profiles, of course.

Keeping track of these things are just a pain in the ass, so I want to have 1 project with 1 code base and just add the images and details (mentioned above) and new versions appear. When I "Archive", I want all of the apps to be build and ready to be send of to apple (which I will have to do manually).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you can use different targets for that job, unfortunately I'm not aware with that. maybe that helps [Building for multiple iPhone targets in XCode](http://www.pacificspirit.com/blog/2009/01/27/building_for_multiple_iphone_targets_in_xcode)

Comment: Awesome, do you know of any good guides that show me how to configure my project?

Comment: Just added a link to my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this before using multiple targets and conditional compilation. You need one target per deliverable. You can configure the name, icons etc for each target in the usual way.

> A set of 50-80 or so images that combine the map of each airport. The filenames are the same in each app. (How do I solve that?)

Keep the images in different directories and for each target only add the images for that app. This technique will also work for the contents of the about page if you can load that from a file.

---

I also use conditional compilation so that I can define different values for my constants for each app.

To do this add a setting to Other C Flags and Other C++ flags to identify your app. Something like:

```
-DAPP_VARIANT=1
```

In your code you can then use the following to implement any app specific behaviour:

```
- (id)init
{
#if APP_VARIANT == 1
    self->server_url = [[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://app1.example.com"] retain];
#elif APP_VARIANT == 2
    self->server_url = [[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://app2.example.com"] retain];
#endif
}
```

Comment: awesome. I will give it a go. I think I can otherwise use the target name, right?

Comment: Is there a macro for the target name? If so then yeah you can use that and the APP_VARIANT is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use one version control branch for all the main code, then fork it six times (once for each airport) where you fill in the data? Once you make new code changes, just push the changes from the main branch to the forks and you're done.

Comment: Hoi Tom! Good idea, however I want to control this from within one project. Every extra line of code, every extra mouse drag, anything that takes extra time is unnecessary. I want to do it the way it was meant to be done, not by using a workaround. I have been doing workarounds so far and with 14 apps out on the App Store, it gets messy.

Comment: Sounds rather easy to automate the pulling etc. Xcode has its own command-line build tools (`xcodebuild`). How is it messy? It allows you to make changes whenever you want, to either the main code or only one airport.

Comment: Well, for starters... its still in SVN and not (yet) in Git or Mecurial (I prefer Mecurial). Second, I believe this is what targets are for... right? I just don't know how to use them.

Comment: My experience with Xcode's targets has been bad to horrible. It's possible to use them like that, but you're guaranteed to run into trouble with them.